# Robot Framework implementation of Python sets

Tags: python, robotframework

I miss sets when I write Robot Framework tests.
I tried to emulate what I need like this:

```
Create Set
    [arguments]    @{elements}
    ${set}=    Evaluate    {e for e in @{elements}}
    [return]    ${set}

Sets Should Be Equal
    [arguments]    ${a}    ${b}
    ${equal}    Evaluate    set(@{a}) == set(@{b})
    Should Be True    ${equal}

Append to Set
    [arguments]    ${set}    ${new}
    Evaluate    ${set}.add(${new})
```

The two first keywords are fine, it seems.

`Append to Set` does not work, `${new}` never gets added to the set. My guess is that the keyword is working on a copy, and since `set.add` returns `None`, the copy gets discarded with no effect.

I've tried to return `${set}` from the keyword, and save the result from the keyword call, to no effect.

robot-log.html looks like this for `Create Set` (working):

[image]

and like this for `Append to Set` (not working):

[image]

I can I modify the set passed as argument?

Another issue is that `Append to Set` requires quoting the new argument, while `Create Set` does not.

Answer (score 2):

For both of your issues the solution is to leave out the `{`, `}` characters around the variable names.

```
Append to Set
    [arguments]    ${set}    ${new}
    Evaluate    $set.add($new)
```

From [`Evaluate`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword's documentation:

> Variables used like ${variable} are replaced in the expression before evaluation. Variables are also available in the evaluation namespace and can be accessed using the special $variable syntax as explained in the [Evaluating expressions section](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions).

From the [Evaluating expressions section](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions):

> Using variables
>
> When a variable is used in the expressing using the normal ${variable}
> syntax, its value is replaced before the expression is evaluated. **This
> means that the value used in the expression will be the string
> representation of the variable value, not the variable value itself.
> This is not a problem with numbers and other objects that have a
> string representation that can be evaluated directly, but with other
> objects the behavior depends on the string representation.** Most
> importantly, strings must always be quoted, and if they can contain
> newlines, they must be triple quoted.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> Should Be True    ${rc} < 10  Return code greater than 10     
> Run Keyword If    '${status}' == 'PASS'   Log     Passed
> Run Keyword If    'FAIL' in '''${output}'''   Log     Output contains FAIL
> ```
>
> **Actual variables values are also available in the evaluation
> namespace. They can be accessed using special variable syntax without
> the curly braces like $variable**. These variables should never be
> quoted.